# Multiple Servlets for specific domain

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, routes

So I'm just getting startet with JSP and Spring and currently i have the following web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>JSP_HelloWorld</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

for my root-url "/". Is it now possible to create a second servlet, for example "users", which serves for all requests to "/users/", so for example "/users/login" would go to the users servlet, but "/aboutus" would still go to the default servlet? So when I request something at "/users/" I only need `@RequestMapping("/login")` instead of `@RequestMapping("/users/login")` in my controllers. Is this even a good approach to split up my application?

Comment: Why you would want to do that at first place? You are using spring so design your controllers per resource and add such resource specific URL's which then be registered so that you can invoke those handler method.

Comment: How would I add a resource specific URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add Controller for each resources you are working with.

In your case "user" is a resource / entity that server is going process request for, So you should add Controller as follows,

```
 @Controller("/users")
 public UserContoller {

  //handler methods
  @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String login(ModelMap model) {
        return "success";
  }
}
```

For other general purpose like login and other you can have another controller with different URL mapping.

```
 @Controller
 public GeneralContoller {

   //handler methods
   @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String login(ModelMap model) {
        return "success";
   }
}
```

Your web.xml servlet mapping is enough for your all requirement as your request will be processed against that mapping.